# What are uncles?

Tags: mining, uncle-blocks

E.g. Etherscan lists mined uncles here http://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0x7c0d52faab596c08f484e3478aebc6205f3f5d8c#uncle ?

What are they and how they differ from normal blocks?

Comment: Read the [Glossary](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Glossary)

Answer (score 1):

Read the [Glossary](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Glossary)

> Uncle: a child of a parent of a parent of a block that is not the parent, or more generally a child of an ancestor that is not an ancestor. If A is an uncle of B, B is a nephew of A.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any layman description available as this description doesn't really tell anything unless you have some insight I don't have? Why? What? Where? How?

Comment: Find an old question, so marked this as duplicate. Read that. It explains much better.